# Need to count the number of times a threshold value is met (or exceeded) per year (using R)

Tags: r, count, subset

I am working with several temperature datasets and trying to pull out when the temperature meets or exceeds a threshold value. Ideally, I want to know how many times (count) that value is met/ exceeded each year for ~100 yrs of data AND when (what date) that value is first exceeded and last exceeded in each year.

Data is in a table (.csv file brought into R) with columns YR, MO, DA, TMAX

For the first part, I have tried using subset to pull out all the times the temperature exceeds a value but then I still have to add up each year (time consuming)
subset(data, TMAX > 20.86)

I've figured out how to use count, but that gives me all the occurrences in the dataset
count(data, vars = "TMAX")

And I have played around with summarise but gotten no where. Any help would be appreciate- especially for the second part of my question- finding the first and last occurrence each year.

Here is sample data. This is SeatlleTMAX (rather than data) as it is the TMAX values for Seattle.
YR     MO   DA  TMAX
1909    9   1   28.9
1909    9   2   30.0
1909    9   3   28.3
1909    9   4   33.9
1909    9   5   31.7
1909    9   6   28.3
1909    9   7   26.7
1909    9   8   23.3
1909    9   9   22.2
1909    9   10  17.8
1909    9   11  14.4
1909    9   12  25.6
1909    9   13  23.9
1909    9   14  25.0
1909    9   15  29.4
1909    9   16  28.3
1909    9   17  14.4
1909    9   18  21.7
1909    9   19  14.4
1909    9   20  13.3
1909    9   21  15.6
1909    9   22  20.6
1909    9   23  23.3
1909    9   24  20.0
1909    9   25  21.1
1909    9   26  22.2
1909    9   27  25.6
1909    9   28  22.2
1909    9   29  15.0
1909    9   30  12.2

Comment: please give us a sample of the data, using `dput(head(data))`

Comment: It looks like you want to group your values by `YR`, then count the number of times some threshold was valued, and also report the first and last exceeded date. In this case, use package `dplyr`, `data %>% group_by(YR) %>% filter(TMAX > 20.86) %>% summarise(number_of_days = n(), first_day = min(DA), last_day = max(DA))`

Comment: This is fantastic, accurately counts the number of threshold days that exceed the TMAX value. When I add the line for first_day and last_day, the problem is it only gives me the day (and not the month) in which the value was exceeded. 

ended up with this: 
SeattleTMaxThres<- SeattleTMAX %>% 
  group_by(YR) %>% filter(TMAX > 20.86) %>% 
  summarise(number_of_days = n(), first_month = min(MO), first_day = min(DA), last_month = max(MO), last_day = max(DA))

is there a more elegant way to do this? (trying to learn, for what I need I will take this and be happy!) Thanks all!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting my comment into an answer, taking into account the presented data and OP's comments. Note, code is not checked as `dput` of data was not obtained.

```
library("dplyr")

data_summarised <-
    data %>% 
    mutate(date = as.Date(paste(YR, MO, DA, sep = "-"))) %>% # concatenate YR MO DA into an ISO date, convert column into date type 
    filter(TMAX > 20.86) %>%
    group_by(YR) %>%
    summarise(number_of_days = n(), # count number of rows in each group
              first_date = min(date),
              last_date = max(date))
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This is fantastic. I had tried to do something similar with the date but failed, very much so appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)    
data %>%
  group_by(YR) %>%
  summarize(n_break_threshold=sum(TMAX > 20.86))
```

This assumes your data is in a `data.frame` called `data`.  What this code says effectively is "Take `data`, set it up so that `dplyr` operations happen on groups of the `data.frame` composed of the unique values in the variable `YR` and then run a summarize operation (i.e. one that returns an atomic vector) that counts the number of times the relation `TMAX > 20.86` is `TRUE`."

You will probably notice this is very similar to `SQL` if you have used that before.

Comment: you should also report on the first and last day of the year in which the threshold was exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

library(plyr)

**Data example**

The example takes a period of two years and selects for temperature randomly values from 0 to 22.

```
dat<-seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), as.Date("2014/12/31"), "days")
DA<-as.numeric(format(dat, "%d"))
MO<-as.numeric(format(dat, "%m"))
YR<-as.numeric(format(dat, "%Y"))
TMAX<-runif(length(dat), 0, 22)

df<-data.frame(dat, DA, MO, YR, TMAX)

Thres=20.86
```

**Count for each month (irrespective of year)**

```
ddply(df, .(MO), summarise, count = sum(TMAX>Thres))
```

**Count for each month in each year**

```
ddply(df, .(YR, MO), summarise, count = sum(TMAX>Thres))
```

**First day that temperature exceeds threshold for each year**

```
temp<-ddply(df, .(YR, dat), summarise, count = sum(TMAX>Thres)) 
res<-subset(temp, count==1)
ddply(res, .(YR), summarise, min = min(dat))
```

**Last day that temperature exceeds threshold for each year**

```
ddply(res, .(YR), summarise, max = max(dat))
```